# OpenCL buffer read error

Tags: c, opencl

I'm developing a OpenCL programm, but when I try to run it, I get this error - and i cannot find anything in google.

When i run the program, I'll get this output:

```
Checking platform "NVIDIA CUDA": trying device "GeForce GTX 560 Ti"... context ok
Trying to load kernel code from "..."... success
Compiler messages are 2 bytes long.
Compiler messages:

Could not enqueue buffer read for 'size': -5
```

I have absolutely no clue why this error occurs and how to fix this?

In my first function I create the arrays and call the scan (an exclusive Naive Scan):

```
local int16_t offsets[64];
local int16_t offsets_out[64];
barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
scan(offsets_out, offsets, pos, self);
```

and here's my scan:

```
void scan(local int16_t *g_odata, local int16_t *g_idata, uint8_t pos, const uint self)
{

    /* Load input into shared memory.
     * This is exclusive scan, so shift right by one
     * and set first element to 0
     */
    offsets[self] = pos;
    offsets_out[self] = pos;
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)  // log2(64) = 6
    {
        uint8_t reg = 1 << (i-1);        // 2^(i-1)
        if (self >= reg)
            g_odata[self] += g_idata[self - reg];
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

        g_idata[self] = g_odata[self];
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    }

    g_odata[self] -= pos;
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you use for creating the buffer and enqueuing the read.

Comment: I edited my answere - when i comment the scan out it works...

Comment: You've shown your kernel code, but the error appears to related to a *host* API call (specifically, reading data from a buffer back to the host). Please show the *host* code, e.g. your calls to `clCreateBuffer` and `clEnqueueReadBuffer`.

Comment: I'm provided with all the code and I just have to implement the kernel - so the host code is working.

Comment: Error -5 is very common on NVidia & it doesn't always mean CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES. Frequently, it can be caused by errors in kernel execution. So, some source code is still required: kernel NDSize settings & the kernel itself (not just function, called inside kernel).

Comment: I'm not responsible for this anymore. I'm no longer into this because this was too long annoying me. I really apreciate your help guys. :) One last question: Does this mean the problem may not be caused by me?